# Publish to Sonatype using NEW gradle plugin: maven-publish

Tags: maven, gradle, publish

So far I am uploading java artifacts to Sonar Nexus using the Gradle `upload` task; for example: https://github.com/oblac/jodd/blob/master/gradle/publish-maven.gradle

Recently I noticed that Gradle has new plugin `maven-publish`. I wanted to use it, as it seems it is going to be the main one for publishing. However, I am not being able to upload it to Nexus. So far, my file looks like this:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

group = 'com.foo'
version = 1.0

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile "...."
}

task sourceJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'sources'
    from sourceSets.main.allJava
}
javadoc {
    failOnError = false
}
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc) {
    classifier = 'javadoc'
    from javadoc.destinationDir
}
publishing {
    publications {
        mavenJava(MavenPublication) {
            from components.java

            artifact sourceJar
            artifact javadocJar
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2"
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.4.1'
}
```

I guess I am missing something? I know I am missing signing, but that is not relevant for uploading. I am not being able to upload artifact using `gradle publish`.

Current error is:

> Could not transfer artifact XXX from/to remote (https://oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2): Could not write to resource 'XXX'.

### EDIT

See final version: https://github.com/igr/repo-url-parser/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: What did you try and what errors do you get? Currently your question is like "why isn't this code working?" which is off-topic on SO.

Comment: Dear @Vampire - I tried everything. This is the minimal file that represents the issue. My questions is: HOW and not WHY. But let me update the question.

Comment: How to do something is also off-topic. You need to state concrete problems you have with the things you tried and the errors you get. You just said "it does not work", that is not an error message or similar.

Comment: Dear @Vampire, I have updated the question. I can't get more concrete that it is now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you miss the authentication information and thus do not have the right to release to Sonatype OSS, as you try to deploy anonymously.

Comment: Sometimes the trivial things are out of sight :))) I will update the question with link to full gradle.build. Thank you!

Comment: I have added identity authentication and still can't publish it. What should I do? It is possible to publish using the maven plugin.

Comment: It is hard to say something if you harvest another question and don't provide any information about your problem. For a working version I wrote you can look at https://github.com/Javacord/Javacord/blob/development/gradle/publishing.gradle