# Publishing is not able to resolve a dependency on a project with multiple publications that have different coordi nates

Tags: java, android, maven, kotlin, maven-publish

I intend to publish my modules in a nexus repository with the following steps.

**first step:**

Create a `android-publications.gradle` file and add the following contents to it

**android-publications.gradle** :

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

ext.moduleVersion = "0.0.0"

def moduleGroupId = "team.techvida.framework"
def moduleRepoUrl = "http://url/repository/maven-releases/"

afterEvaluate {
    publishing {
        publications {
            debug(MavenPublication) {
                from components.debug
                groupId = moduleGroupId
                artifactId = "$project.name-debug"
                version = moduleVersion
            }
            release(MavenPublication) {
                from components.release
                groupId = moduleGroupId
                artifactId = project.name
                version = moduleVersion
            }
        }
        repositories {
            maven {
                name "nexus"
                url moduleRepoUrl
                allowInsecureProtocol = true
                credentials {
                    username findProperty("nexusUsername")
                    password findProperty("nexusPassword")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Step two**
Use it in all modules as follows:

core module =>

```
apply from: "$rootDir/android-library-build.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/buildSrc/android-publications.gradle"
ext.moduleVersion = "0.0.1"
dependencies {

}
```

presentation module =>

```
apply from: "$rootDir/android-library-build.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/buildSrc/android-publications.gradle"
ext.moduleVersion = "0.0.1"
dependencies {

}
```

**Third step**
Use in a module that uses other modules

di module =>

```
apply from: "$rootDir/android-library-build.gradle"
apply from: "$rootDir/buildSrc/android-publications.gradle"
ext.moduleVersion = "0.0.1"

dependencies {
    implementation(project(Modules.core))
    implementation(project(Modules.imageLoading))
    implementation(project(Modules.prettyLogger))
}
```

Note 1 : Publishing the second step modules is done successfully.

**Step 4** (which leads to a compilation error)
Publish the third step module (di)

Received error:

```
 What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':di:publishReleasePublicationToNexusRepository'.
> Publishing is not able to resolve a dependency on a project with multiple publications that have different coordi
nates.
  Found the following publications in project ':image_loading':
    - Maven publication 'debug' with coordinates team.techvida.framework:image_loading-debug:0.0.1
    - Maven publication 'release' with coordinates team.techvida.framework:image_loading:0.0.1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run
with --scan to get full insights.
```

Would you please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Gradle and the `maven-publish` plugin, but maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42908823/publish-to-sonatype-using-new-gradle-plugin-maven-publish.

Comment: @Oliver Thank you for your attention, this link did not solve my problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Publishing is not able to resolve a dependency on a project with multiple publications that have different coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51247830/publishing-is-not-able-to-resolve-a-dependency-on-a-project-with-multiple-public)